# How can i register and handle linux reboot signal?

Tags: embedded-linux

if i issue reboot command, i get the message

## reboot

....
....
The system is going down for reboot NOW!
INIT: Sending processes the TERM signal
....

Therefore "init" sends TERM to all processes and i registered TERM as following

```
void sig_handler(int signum, siginfo_t *siginfo, void *ctx)
{
    printf("!!! sig_handler: signum: %d\n", signum);
    if (signum == SIGTERM && (long) siginfo->si_pid == 1)
    {
        printf("!!! sig_handler: send by init-process\n");
    }
    exit(signum);
}

void sig_handler_reg(int signum)
{
    struct sigaction act;
    memset(&act, '\0', sizeof(act));
    act.sa_sigaction = sig_handler;
    act.sa_flags = SA_SIGINFO;
    sigaction(signum, &act, NULL);
    printf("!!! sig_handler_reg: signum %d registered\n", signum);
}
```

i issue the command on command line

## pkill my_process

and i get the message

!!! sig_handler: signum: 15

i issue the command on command line

## reboot

and i get no message from sig_handler and the system reboots

What is wrong ?

every hint appreciated

Answer (score 1):

The signal is sent to the every process running to terminate

Your process's parent process is killed so your process becomes orphan and hence gets adopted by init and it forceably reboots the sysytem without waiting for your process to terminate

Comment: thanx for your response. the parent of my process is init because i started my process in /etc/init.d/rc.local

Comment: what do you mean ? how can i trigger on reboot ?